# PHP T_STRING Error in Header Location

Tags: php

I keep getting this error..

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\inetpub\storeboard.com\oauth\callback.php on line 39

What am I doing wrong with this line of code? This is line 39

```
  header('Location: ./save_twitter_tokens.php?nToken='.$access_token["oauth_token"].'&nSecret='.$access_token["oauth_token_secret"].');
```

Comment: at the very end of the line, you have opened the string again but not closed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will work:

```
  header('Location: ./save_twitter_tokens.php?nToken='.$access_token["oauth_token"].'&nSecret='.$access_token["oauth_token_secret"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in the syntax highlighting of the code you posted. The last string doesn't get closed. Remove the `.'` at the end.